# org.apache.xmlgraphics fop + org.lesscss lesscss conflict

Tags: java, maven, apache-fop

I have a conflict using two packages in my java project - apache fop and lesscss.
I figured out the reason of the error - less compiler uses

`context.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_7);`

in it's constructor, where context is an object of class org.mozilla.javascript.Context (rhino package).
But apache fop has patched version of this object (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-js/1.7), which doesn't support 1.7 language version.
So here is extremely simplified set of files, which can demonstrate my issue. All you need is

1) pom.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
            <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
            <version>1.7R4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

2) Some test servlet with the following content:

```
package main;

import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_7);
    }
}
```

Compiling this using **mvn clean package** will cause

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad language version: 170

That's because patched (by fop) Context is using, but I want Rhino original Context, which supports 1.7 version. If you remove fop dependency from pom.xml, everything will work just fine.

So how can I use both fop and lesscss without any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this problem in production and solved it by removing batik-js from the classpath.

Empirically, org.apache.xmlgraphics 1.7 works fine with rhino 1.7R4 (unpatched), which is what org.lesscss/lesscss 1.3.3 depends on.  So, just exclude batik-js from your build/classpath.